# C++ SQLite3 Error - undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'

Tags: c++, sqlite, linker

Im using CodeBlocks and Im trying to execute this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    sqlite3* DB;
    int exit = 0;
    exit = sqlite3_open("example.db", &DB);

    if (exit) {
        std::cerr << "Error open DB " << sqlite3_errmsg(DB) << std::endl;
        return (-1);
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Opened Database Successfully!" << std::endl;
    sqlite3_close(DB);
    return (0);
}
```

But I receives this errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: Cywin) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test\test\main.cpp|8|undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'|
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test\test\main.cpp|11|undefined reference to `sqlite3_errmsg'|
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test\test\main.cpp|16|undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

I've moved Sqlite3.c and Sqlite3.h to MinGW include folder, I imagine that its a link error, if anyone can help me it could be perfect.

Comment: You forgot to add `Sqlite3.c` to your project.

Comment: How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite3.c is a source file. It has nothing to do in the MinGW include folder. To add  Sqlite3.c to your project you can take a look at:
http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Creating_a_new_project#Adding_a_pre-existing_file